# OpenSSH Ubuntu Team

Tags: ssh, packaging, openssh

I am dealing with a multi-process sshd problem regarding the privilege separation directory. I have been in contact with the OpenSSH team and I have reviewed their source code, specifically: OpenSSH 7.6p1.

Somehow the Ubuntu release of OpenSSH 7.6p1 changed the definition of the `_PATH_PRIVSEP_CHROOT_DIR` from `/var/empty` to `/run/sshd`.

- Who is the team at Ubuntu that ports OpenSSH from the public version to the Ubuntu version?
- Where is the modified source code, or modification process, of OpenSSH 7.6p1 exist?
- How do I get in contact with the OpenSSH Ubuntu import team?

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openssh-client and https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/1:7.6p1-4

Answer (score 1):

All of the info is hosted on Launchpad. The [openssh server package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh) on Launchpad points to an [openssh debian team](https://launchpad.net/~debian-ssh). You can find the members on [gitlab](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/project_members).

Ubuntu developers are not specific related to openssh server; they do have the client under their wings. You can find then on the [mailinglists](https://lists.ubuntu.com/).